# How to set focus on a textbox in Angular

Tags: angular

How can I set focus on an element (such as a textbox) in a component's template? I have tried the below code.

Html:

```
<input #input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="person.Name" class="form-control" />
```

Component:

```
import {Component, Input, Output, AfterContentInit, ContentChild,                   
    AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit, ViewChild,ViewChildren} from 'angular2/core';

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit,AfterViewChecked { 
    @ViewChildren('input') vc;

    ngAfterViewInit() {            
        this.vc.first.nativeElement.focus();
    }
```

But it's giving an error.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ElementRef`, tested and working with Angular 4.0.1:

```ts
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('input') vc: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.vc.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/D42la7n4XvAGiNZiuoA4?p=preview)

Comment: This only works intermittently for me, and that seems to be the case for quite a few people attempting the same thing.  Sometimes it focus' and other times it doesn't.